# Issue using Glassfish 4.1.2 on Intellij 2017.2.4

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

I'm using jdk 8, i've set up glassfish as shown [here](http://thebrainyprofessionals.com/2015/02/07/setup-glassfish-server-in-intellij/) , but when i run it i have

`Detected server admin port: 4848
 Detected server http port: 8080
 GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0
 C:\Users\Talon\Desktop\tools\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat stop-domain domain1`

`Process finished with exit code 0
 GlassFish requires Java SE version 6.  Your JDK is version 0`

And once i disconnect i have `Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:4848` while i specified port 8080 in the configuration. Under deployment i also have `"project name":war exploded`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's because you're using JDK 9. Java 9 changed the version scheme for Java, so the version isn't being detected properly. GlassFish 4.1.2 will not work on Java 9 even ignoring this issue due to the introduction of the JPMS module system. You will need to run GlassFish on Java 8.

Comment: Under `Run/Debug Configuration > JRE` says i'm using Default (1.8)